# I have a 5 day trip planned in 2 months and I just got hired at my new job. How do I tell them without losing my job?

Tags: management

I got a job at a bakery and I am a cashier. the problem is that I love this job and I would hate to lose it because of my planned trip in 2 months. It's 5 days long and I would probably need another day of rest after the trip. How should I tell my manager about my trip?

Comment: you should tell him *immediately*

Comment: Related (dupe?): http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1330/325

Comment: @MonicaCellio good find

Comment: I've answered this question before; that's how I knew it was there. :-)

Comment: The real question is "how do you *not* tell them and *keep* your job?"

Answer (score 12):

This may come a bit too late for your situation, but when I was a similar situation before (twice already, actually) I mentioned it when signing the contract.

I told HR, or the manager, whoever handed me the contract, that I had planned vacation, which was scheduled, paid for, and my partner had also scheduled days off for it. I offered to shift the starting date to after the vacation was over, take unpaid leave or take it out of my regular vacation days (even though it might not have been company policy to allow vacation days during probation period).

Neither company held it aganist me, but allowed me to start right away and chose one of the other two options, which was fine.

Since you already started your job, the situation is not exactly the same, but I would still try it. Walk up to your boss, ask them for a one-on-one and tell them you neglected to mention this before but would like to discuss it now, to avoid any problems with it.

Tell them what I mentioned above. Obviously you can't offer them to move the starting date since you started already, so I think, you have to at least mention the offer of cancelling the trip. But also do make it clear that there are other people involved that are counting on this planned trip happening (like my partner in the above example).

You *have to* be prepared to cancel the trip to not lose the job, but I don't think it's going to happen.

Comment: Would you be prepared to take the time off without pay, rather than cancel the trip? If so, offer that as an option.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine this being a problem. I was in a similar, but not identical position, when I started at my previous workplace. I had accepted the job offered, signed the contract and sent it back.

However, I hadn't mentioned at the interview stage that I had a family wedding on the Friday at the end of my second week.

Officially I hadn't accrued enough annual leave to take the day off, but I asked (politely) via email to HR before I started and they obliged. No problems at all.

My situation was only one day, but i'd recommend going back to them on email before you start and asking them if they are ok with you taking your pre-planned holiday.