# Asking for vacation on new job

Tags: new-job, vacation

I have been planing a longer trip with a friend. When we started planing this trip I had another job. The thing is that now that we are going to book the flight, I have changed jobs. I haven't even started yet, the vacation is going to be in a few months so i will work some time before it. Yet i think it might look bad if the first thing i do at a new job is to ask for a vacation. (it is going to be a longer trip roughly 1 month)

The law only allows me to take out unpaid vacation, so that might soften the blow, yet how do i bring this up?

Comment: How long are you planning for this trip? And I think you could (should) have brought this up during your interviews for this new job.

Comment: A **one month** vacation? Why on earth wouldn't you [disclose this during the negotiation step](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/when-should-i-tell-my-new-employer-about-an-already-planned-vacation?rq=1)? Frankly the only way to bring this up is to preface the request with "I understand if this is too soon" which means being prepared that you probably won't be able to take that vacation. Beyond that this is basically a (more serious) duplicate of [I have a 5 day trip planned in 2 months and I just got hired at my new job.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19125/)

Comment: This question needs a country tag.

Answer (score 8):

Taking a months vacation, unpaid or not, is not a good look if you just started the new job.  The time to bring up a vacation that is scheduled during the initial phase of employment was during the final stages of negotiation.

To answer your question:  While the law may allow it, **I doubt this will be much comfort to your employer**.  Companies hire because they have to work do, and a new hire taking a long vacation that was not planned for is going to hurt the companies planned throughput.

I would **recommend re-scheduling this vacation**.  Using this approach, you may be able to take some of the trip with pay, and the company can properly plan for the resource (*you*) being on vacation.

Comment: +1, and often plane ticket can be rescheduled without major fee

Answer (score 4):

The time to bring this up was on the last round of interviews / negotiations.

I had this happened to me. I solved it by being honest, and saying something like:

> I really want to work for you, but there is one minor thing, I already have my vacation trip booked and wouldn't like to change my plans. Is there a chance to get vacation between Y-m-d and Y-m-d? Or to arrange my start so I end my previous job before my trip nad start working for you when I'll return?

It helps if you are a specialist, and not just a body in workforce.

---

How to bring this up now? **Ask your manager.** Admit that you should have to speak about it on your interview but failed. It will help if you will add that working for them was so much more important than your vacation that you didn't even consider it. **And be prepared not to go** on your vacation, if you will see he looks disappointed.

If you are on your trial period and it's going to end before your trip, it might be good to ask them when it ends, when you are sure they want to keep you and when you are about to sign a new contract anyway. Another round of negotiations will give you another chance. Sure, tickets will be much, much more expensive then, but that's the risk and proce of not thinking about it earlier.