# Negotiating over time off

Tags: job-offer

Is it prudent or feasible to negotiate unpaid time off when Job offer is offered.  IE I have planned on taking time off during Christmas is it unheard of to ask for unpaid time off during 4 days of the holiday time.

Comment: I would have thought that would be ok as most people do. Probably can have it as paid time off

Comment: @EdHeal It would be unlikely to be paid time off as there would not have been enough time to accrue sufficient leave by then.

Comment: Depends. In the UK it would be possible. I started a job and had the second week off paid as salary is paid after the event

Comment: @EdHeal Here you may be allowed to push your leave accrual into a negative balance, but it very much depends on the employer. Otherwise, you can ask for unpaid leave.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1330/when-should-i-tell-my-new-employer-about-an-already-planned-vacation may have some useful info. It also features one of the lowest-rated answers I've ever seen, so don't follow that guy's advice. :-)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of the question Carson linked to?

Answer (score 7):

This is absolutely a normal thing to do, and you are doing it at exactly the right time - i.e. right when you have a job offer but before you accept it.

Don't necessarily jump straight to 'unpaid time off' unless you want to. Just tell them that you have plans at that time and would they be able to give you the time off. Most firms are likely to be OK with this. They may offer you unpaid time off, or even offer to let you use some paid time off in advance.