# New job. How to tell boss about already planned vacation?

Tags: vacation

I started a job a week ago in a startup and I'm a bit of a slow learner.For now, I'm working in home and from next week we're gonna have our own office. The thing is I didn't mention that I already booked tickets, hotel and everything before I got this job. I have booked holidays for a week in another country.

This job is huge for me since I was unemployed for nearly a year so I don't want to have a bad impression at this one. I can't postpone my visit since my visa expires soon. I already a lot on this.

I'd like to tell him I plan on working on Saturday and Sunday to make up for the leave and I'd be willing to cancel the visit for the job. The office starts on Feb 15th and I was thinking of advancing my holiday plans to next week, finish my holidays and start working from Feb 25th instead of taking leave after joining the office. Is this is a good idea? I won't be taking leaves after that.

How and when should I inform my boss about this?

Comment: You should have told your boss before you started... as you haven't said something immediately. You can't just walk out of the office for a week it out telling them.

Comment: I haven't been assigned any work. I've just been told to obtain knowledge of their technologies. Should I tell him now?

Comment: The sooner the better.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1330/44333

Comment: You should put your big boy pants and accept the fact that it was your mistake not bringing this up earlier/during meetings. I would cancel the vacation and be a professional. If you had already a lot of money invested in this holiday getaway you should've invested a bit of more effort and time in addressing it during the interviews.

Answer (score 12):

> How and when should I inform my boss about this?

Covering the "When" first - you should have told them before you accepted the job offer, as part of the negotiations. And that's the point when you should have been willing to cancel your travel plans if that's what it would take to get the job, given how important this job is to you.

Obviously that didn't happen. So now you need to tell them as soon as possible, i.e. RIGHT NOW!

As for the "How" - you get them on the phone (since you're not working in an office with them at the moment), you apologize profusely for overlooking the fact that you needed to let them know about these travel plans, and you fill them in on the details. And you also tell him that they can be moved (if they can be) or cancelled (if you're willing to cancel them if your employer is inflexible), and make your offer of weekend work to mitigate the interruption to you getting up to speed with their tech.

Comment: Would it be better to tell them on phone or mail since it's quite hard for me to reach him on phone ( My boss is traveling right now ). Ultimately, my job comes first. I will apologize for mentioning at the last moment.

Comment: @Peele  The order for informing your boss is:  1. In person; 2. On the phone; 3. Email.

Comment: Alright, I'll give him a call and talk to him about this. I hope this doesn't create a bad impression.

Comment: The biggest problem with leave very early on in a new job is that they have probably planned some sort of induction period for you, which is much less miss-able than the subsequent weeks. If informed at interview they might well have said "start after the holiday" - but that ship has sailed now.

Comment: Its a fairly new company, there's no induction program ( I asked about this) and there's no training as well. I'd have to learn everything on my own.

Comment: @Peele speaking on the phone is always better than firing off an email, when it's possible. If you can't get hold of your boss on the phone easily, then I guess I would recommend emailing rather than letting even more time pass before explaining the situation.