# Interviewed for job and have several doctor appointments scheduled

Tags: new-job

I have interviewed for a job and feel I may be offered it. I currently have several doctor appointments scheduled.  I wouldn't want this to affect their decision to hire me.

Should I tell them before they hire me?

Comment: I think there are good answers below, predicated on what you mean by "several doctor appointments." If you mean 3 or 4 over the next several months, that's probably not a big deal. If you mean 3 or 4 every week for the next several months, I think it's only fair to both the employer and yourself to discuss upfront. Employers can't make hiring decisions based on medical conditions (at least in the US) but if you have so many appointments *that you won't be able to perform the job*, that's another story.

Comment: What does the appointments have to do with the job? Would they take place after you'd expect to start?

Comment: Somewhat related: [When should I tell my new employer about an already-planned vacation?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1330)

Answer (score 9):

> Should I tell them before they hire me?

**No**, there is no need to add this complication until a hiring decision is made.  Once you accept the offer, *immediately let the hiring manager know* the dates and times of the appointments.

You won't be the first person they have hired to have commitments already made. (Dr. appointments, vacations scheduled and paid for, etc.)

Long story short, this *should* be no big deal.  **If it is**, I would seriously re-evaluate whether I want to work for them or not.

Comment: I think this is the right answer. +1 "_Once you accept the offer, immediately let the hiring manager know_"

Answer (score 0):

You're overthinking this horribly. Managers understand that people exist as human beings outside the workplace. But there's also no point to disclosing information that's not relevant to the hiring process and would impact something that might not even happen.

**On your first day (or week)**, just mention that you have pre-scheduled personal appointments and will need to be out of the office for a couple hours on whatever day it is.